# Retrieving attachments from Microsoft Planner tasks through Graph API

Tags: c#, api, microsoft-graph-api

I currently using Microsoft Graph to interface with PLanner and I am attempting to set up a program to be able to fully read in all data about Groups, Plans, Buckets and the Tasks.

The API has a lot of power and so far I can read in everything (even each individual comment) but for the life of me, I can't seem to find a way to read in attachments of a task!

The API documentation doesn't seem to indicate that there is any relationship between tasks and attachments either, implying that on Planner, there shouldn't even be an attachment.

Planner Task Object Documentation: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/plannertask

The closet the API has is Post attachments, in the comments section. (See this: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/post) but no matter hwo i use that, it won't read in attachments to the task itself on planner as that List Attachments function simply returns empty for every post. (Because on Planner itself, the attachment is attached to the task, not an individual post)

In fact, the Get Attachment documentation details the different ways you can get attachments (see: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/attachment_get) showing you can get it from calendar events, posts or events. But not tasks, like Planner allows!

Is there something I am missing from the documentation or is this just something the API doesn't allow yet? I also can't really find anyone else talking about it online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Planner attachments are just links to external resources, stored on the [task details](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/plannertaskdetails) object of the task. On the task details, [external references collection](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/plannerexternalreferences) contains the URL of all the references of the task, which can be used to access the proper resource.

Comment: any idea what permissions are required to download the external references? (even though they are stored in SharePoint)

Comment: I believe this is the API to use to download the files in SharePoint/OneDrive : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
It explains how it works and what permissions are required. You should create a new question if you encounter issues or have problems so people can see and respond.