# Download an externalReference from PlannerTask using the Graph API

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I'd like to download a file attached to a PlannerTask. I already have the [external references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47940869/retrieving-attachments-from-microsoft-planner-tasks-through-graph-api) but I can't figure out how to access the file.

An external reference is a JSON object like this:

```
{
  "https%3A//contoso%2Esharepoint%2Ecom/sites/GroupName/Shared%20Documents/AnnualReport%2Epptx":
  {
    // ... snip ...
  }
}
```

I've tried to use the following endpoint

```
GET /groups/{group-id}/drive/root:/sites/GroupName/Shared%20Documents/AnnualReport%2Epptx
```

but I get a 404 response. Indeed, when I use the query in Graph Explorer it gives me a warning about "Invalid whitespace in URL" (?).

A workaround that I've found is to use the `search` endpoint to look for files like this:

```
GET /groups/{group-id}/drive/root/search(q='AnnualReport.pptx')
```

and hope the file name is unique.

Anyway, with both methods I need extra information (ie. the `group-id`) that may not be readily available by the time I have the external reference object.

What is the proper way to get a download url for a driveItem that is referenced by an external reference object in a PlannerTask?

Do I really need the group-id to access such file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys in external references are `webUrl` instances, so they can be used with the `/shares/` endpoint. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174302/ms-graph-api-weburl-to-driveitem) for details on how to do it.

When you get a `driveItem` object, the download url is available from `AdditionalData`: `driveItem.AdditionalData["@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl"]`. You can use `WebClient.DownloadFile` to [download the file on the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/525368).

Here is the final code:

```
var remoteUri = "https%3A//contoso%2Esharepoint%2Ecom/sites/GroupName/Shared%20Documents/AnnualReport%2Epptx";
var localFile = "/tmp/foo.pptx";

string sharingUrl = remoteUri;
string base64Value = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sharingUrl));
string encodedUrl = "u!" + base64Value.TrimEnd('=').Replace('/','_').Replace('+','-');

DriveItem driveItem = m_graphClient
    .Shares[encodedUrl]
    .DriveItem
    .Request()
    .GetAsync().Result;

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(driveItem.AdditionalData["@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl"].ToString(), 
                        localFile);
}
```